# JavaScript para cada registro em minha view

Tags: javascript, html5, asp.net-mvc-4

Tenho uma *VIEW* em que exibo uma tabela com 15 registros (15 linhas) e 5 colunas, mas o que interessa mesmo é uma coluna, "Ações". Nela tenho 1 botão, "Visualizar", que ao clicar, ***quero abrir uma janela com uma mensagem, para testes***.

Porém, apenas o primeiro registro, ao clicar no botão "Visualizar", exibe a janela com a mensagem, os demais 14 registros não.

Como faço para que todos os registros/linhas exibam a mensagem?

Segue abaixo código:

**VIEW CSHTML**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="header text-center" style="width: 100px;"> Ações </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tabela">     
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @this.Hidden("IdClient").Value(item.Id)
                    <a id="visualizarCliente" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-visualizar" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Visualizar" target="_blank" 
                      href="@Url.Action(MVC.Painel.Clientes.Visualizar(item.Id))">
                        <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#visualizarCliente").click(function () {
            var idCliente = $("#IdClient").val();
            window.alert("Teste");
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que você está usando o seletor `id` e ele não pode se repetir. Troque para outro seletor qualquer, como `data-toggle="tooltip"` por exemplo.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("a[data-toggle='tooltip']").click(function () {
            window.alert("Teste");
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

O ideal nesse caso seria usar uma modal. 
e passar o valor de cada id para a modal ficaria bem mas prático.
ele acharia a id e mostraria determinadas funções de cada Id.